# Excel Chart data table. Formatting one row (TOTAL) only

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, formatting, format

Im trying to build a chart and Highlight TOTAL row in data table (that one underlined on screen) ;).

I can format only whole chart data table or nothing.
By a trick I did a "hidden" (no colour and border) Total chart element, but i would like to make this row bold and a bit larger font [image: Chart]

Comment: You mean to say that,, you want Highlight Total Row in Chart (Data Table) or in Table in Worksheet !! If Looking to format TABLE on Chart then available formats can be applied on Whole Table now on any specific portion,, you may link the Table to Source also.

Answer (score -1):

Exactly i need to highlight/bold/change font to bit larger, to that i marked by red (only) on Data Table under chart.
It's a bit strange thet no one need such thing before and its possible to whole table or nothing. So maybe in office 2025 M$ will add such thing.